# How Can I Fix Huge Log File Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am managing a legacy system (very legacy) using SQL 2000 and I have a 190gb ldf transaction log file which is beginning to drag the system down.

Usually I would back up the offending file which would then obviously free up the space, however there are a number of complications which make this currently difficult.

The system is on a hyper-v server which is replicated and the drive has 30gb free space with no ability to expand the drive.

My plan is to create a new transaction log file, stop the growth of the 190gb file and then delete the 190gb file after a few days, thereby freeing up the space.

My simple question is - would this work?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=huge+log+file+site%3Adba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately the only things I can find relate to newer versions of SQL. This is SQL2000 and really I would like to know if I'm on the right path with this or not.

Comment: SS2000 has been a long time since I worked with that, but IIRC it also had the notions of SIMPLE and FULL Recovery Models? Am I right in thinking you have a SIMPLE recovery model for the database?

Comment: Hi TT, yep it's simple.

Comment: You realize the risk of not having a current full backup, correct? That said, 2000 did support attach / detach which is a risky alternative to shrinking. A rather long discussion of [large log files here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space). Specifically the remarks from Aaron.

Comment: I am fully aware of the risks, hence why I'm trying to sort it out. I have only recently become involved in this and am trying to sort out other peoples mistakes and lack of foresight, so please, less of the sarcastic responses aimed at me. I am looking at every avenue to try and get this server working.